# Image doesn't show in Anki (although the media file exists)

Tags: import, export, anki

Front template:

[image: Card's Front template]

Anki's media folder:

[image: Anki's media folder]

Front Preview:

[image: The card's front's preview]

Strangely, if I replace '7' by '8' in the Front Template, the image shows.

[image: Vive la petite difference!]

Answer (score 0):

The following steps solve the problem.

1. Open the corrupt file in [Preview](https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT201740) (in my system Preview is the default image editor, so it opens automatically when the file is double-clicked).
2. Save the file to the Desktop, keeping the original name and extension.
3. Copy the file from the Desktop back to Anki's media folder, overwriting the original.

* It might be possible to combine steps 2 & 3 by simply saving the file back to the media folder, however Preview's Save... dialogue doesn't let me save back to the media folder, hence the extra step of saving to the Desktop.

---

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43434325/how-to-automate-the-opening-and-saving-of-a-corrupt-png-image-file-in-an-image) for an attempt to solve this problem programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and it turns out I was using the wrong unicode character for double quotes ""

Just in case somebody else stumbles on this as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

- Exporting of single Deck (.apkg) with .png pictures and importing it at a different computer or different profile on the same computer => pictures are not shown
- Exporting the whole collection (.colpkg) and importing it works fine => pictures are shown correctly

Checking the database or media inside Anki does not show any problems.
I use Anki 2.1.58.

So I looked inside the media folder and discovered what has gone wrong...
[image: The original media folder contains valid png files]
The original media folder contains valid png files.
I can open such a file and view it with a external picture viewer.

[image: The imported profile contains currupted files which are smaller]
The imported profile contains currupted files which are smaller.
If I try to open such a file my picture viewer tells me that the file is currupted!

> In conclusion I can say that "something" with the export or import
> does not work properly.
> **The solution I have for this problem is either to export and import the whole collection of all decks or to copy the media files
> manually.**

--- Edit ---

I analyzed the file format .apkg

- If I rename a file `MyExport.apkg` to `MyExport.zip` then I am able to unpack the file and get a single file for each media plus an additional file `collection.anki2` which contains the database (so .apkg is basically a zip file)
- All contained files **are already corrupted**!!!
- In that way I can prove that the **export routine** does have an error and not the import

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug randomly occurs when anki reads file names. Try to rename your files.

This two files are identical:
[image: example]

Here we can see anki can read only short name:
[image: example 2]