# How to use python to imitate the opening and saving of an image file in an image editor?

Tags: python, image, python-3.x, save, png

I encountered a certain problem with corrupt `.png` image files* that I was able to overcome by simply opening them in an image editor (Apple's [Preview](https://support.apple.com/en-il/HT201740)) and saving them back, without making any explicit changes.

I have thousands of similarly corrupt image files that need to be subjected to the same procedure. Is there a way to automate it in python?

The following naive code doesn't work:

```
>>> with open('an_image.png', 'rb') as f:
...     data = f.read()  
... with open('an_image.png', 'wb') as f:
...     f.write(data)
```

Why doesn't this code work? What does the image editor do that corrects the problem, and how can I imitate it programmatically?

My operating system is macOS Sierra Version 10.12.4.
My python version is 3.6.1.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5uXX.png) is an example of one of the corrupt files.

---

* For those interested, the original problem is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43429714/1818935).

Comment: SYS read/write doesn't change anything. Try to do it with a Image module like PIL.

Comment: It would be helpful to know the nature of the file corruption.  Could you post one of your corrupt images?

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson: The nature of the corrption is explained in the post that I linked to at the end of the post.

Comment: That post has some screen shots but no actual PNG images that I could find.  If you don't want to post one of those images, try "pngcheck -v file.png" for diagnostic information about it.

Comment: @GlennRanders-Pehrson: I've updated my post with one of the corrupt files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example file, https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5uXX.png, isn't actually a PNG file.  It's a ["CgBI" file](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/CgBI_file_format) instead, which is a PNG-like file created by Apple X-code software, probably using their rogue "pngcrush" application.  There are various ways of recovering a valid PNG file from a CgBI file (except for unavoidable loss of precision in the underlying color values of non-opaque pixels).

- The Apple-modified pngcrush is itself capable
  of reverting the "iPhone optimizations"
- There are third-party applications such as the public domain, open source
  [pngdefry](http://www.jongware.com/pngdefry.html) application
  that can be found on the net.

Apologies for not showing you how to invoke pngdefry or pngcrush via python calls, but hopefully this will set you on the right track, and at least tell you what has happened to your files.

Legal Notice: I am required to note that Apple and iPhone
are registered trademarks of Apple, Inc.

Comment: Thanks! Does pngdefry also have the problem of loss of precision in the underlying color values of non-opaque pixels?

Comment: Yes, it's unavoidable.  Consider a pixel of any color whose alpha is 0 (RGBA={R,G,B,0})  The CgBI file will represent that pixel as RGBA={0,0,0,0} and the underlying color is irretrievably lost.